# ActiveRecord - illegal mix of collations

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, character-encoding

I am having some issue with Ruby's ActiveRecord with the Redmine application.

```
Started PATCH "//issues/33135" for [ipaddress] at 2015-06-02 17:02:48 -0700
Processing by IssuesController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"[secret_token]", "issue"=>{"is_private"=>"0", "project_id"=>"949", "tracker_id"=>"4", "subject"=>"adgsasdg", "description"=>"asdggsad", "status_id"=>"1", "priority_id"=>"1", "assigned_to_id"=>"", "parent_issue_id"=>"", "start_date"=>"2015-06-02", "due_date"=>"2015-06-17", "done_ratio"=>"0", "custom_field_values"=>{"349"=>"", "32"=>"", "33"=>"", "67"=>"", "63"=>"", "221"=>"", "209"=>"0", "362"=>"", "234"=>"", "237"=>"", "235"=>[""], "435"=>""}, "notes"=>"", "private_notes"=>"0", "lock_version"=>"0"}, "was_default_status"=>"1", "time_entry"=>{"hours"=>"", "activity_id"=>"", "comments"=>"", "custom_field_values"=>{"388"=>"", "387"=>""}}, "last_journal_id"=>"", "commit"=>"Submit", "id"=>"33135"}
  Current user: [username] (id=3)
Mysql2::Error: Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (latin1_swedish_ci,NUMERIC) for operation '>': INSERT INTO `journal_details` (`property`, `prop_key`, `old_value`, `value`, `journal_id`) VALUES ('cf', '32', '2015-06-25', '', 56006)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 811ms (ActiveRecord: 93.6ms)

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (latin1_swedish_ci,NUMERIC) for operation '>': INSERT INTO `journal_details` (`property`, `prop_key`, `old_value`, `value`, `journal_id`) VALUES ('cf', '32', '2015-06-25', '', 56006)):
  app/models/journal.rb:67:in `save'
  app/models/issue.rb:1566:in `create_journal'
  app/models/issue.rb:175:in `create_or_update'
  app/controllers/issues_controller.rb:479:in `block in save_issue_with_child_records'
  app/controllers/issues_controller.rb:467:in `save_issue_with_child_records'
  app/controllers/issues_controller.rb:180:in `update'
```

All my tables show collations of utf8 (some ...general_ci and some ...unicode_ci, but UTF8 nevertheless) and the error says I have some latin1...

I dont completely understand what this means...
Does it mean that it is trying to go from utf8 to latin1? or vice-versa? (does it matter?)

---

### What I have Tried:

- I have tried setting all database tables to a utf8 collation.
- I have also tried looking up:

  `select collation_name 
  from information_schema.columns where table_schema = 'redmine' and collation_name like '%' group by table_name;`

  where collation name is like utf% or latin% and it only shows utf8's and NULLs. latin% search was empty.
- Show Variables:

  `character_set_client    utf8
  character_set_connection    utf8
  character_set_database  latin1
  character_set_filesystem    binary
  character_set_results   utf8
  character_set_server    latin1
  character_set_system    utf8
  collation_connection    utf8_general_ci
  collation_database  latin1_swedish_ci
  collation_server    latin1_swedish_ci`

  in general, im guessing that it looks like the database stores in latin, but the connections are done in utf8?
  Could this be causing this issue?

---

What is the issue? How can I solve it? Anyone else see something similar?

Im still trying to narrow it down to either the database or the application side of things.

Comment: Can you also post your active record call `JournalDetail.create(property: 'cf' )`  just to make sure what is that you are doing

Comment: @MZaragoza "INSERT INTO `journal_details` (`property`, `prop_key`, `old_value`, `value`, `journal_id`) VALUES ('cf', '32', '2015-06-25', '', 56006)" is that enough information?? (edited the original post with it)

Comment: Do you have the activerecord call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Summary

I forced a UTF8 collation and converted the data being compared to UTF8 for the actual comparison operation.

---

For some reason, a database trigger I was using (and have been using without issue for 4 months) is the source of the problem.
I suspect a change in the database, but unsure.

In the trigger, there is a line (and only one line) that compares a `new.value` to a `due_date` with a "`>`" comparison operator.

I first tried adding COLLATE to the statement, but then my error changed to:

```
Mysql2::Error: COLLATION 'utf8_unicode_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'latin1': INSERT INTO `journal_details` (`property`, `prop_key`, `old_value`, `value`, `journal_id`) VALUES ('cf', '32', '2015-06-16', '', 56863)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 846ms (ActiveRecord: 69.0ms)

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: COLLATION 'utf8_unicode_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'latin1': INSERT INTO `journal_details` (`property`, `prop_key`, `old_value`, `value`, `journal_id`) VALUES ('cf', '32', '2015-06-16', '', 56863)):"
```

So then I tried:

Adding both Convert() and Collate to the statement

```
NEW.value > CONVERT(Due_date USING utf8)

COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
```

and everything works fine again. =)

---

---

**Extra:**

MySQL DBA says there were no changes to the DB recently... so its Very odd that this kind of error would pop up at the time that it did... I would really like to know the real cause of the issue so I could fix THAT instead. 
I still suspect something to do with the database collations & character sets, but one thing that makes me doubt this is the fact that my **Dev environment machine has all character sets and collations set to UTF8**, whereas my **Prod environment database has**

```
character_set_client    utf8
character_set_connection    utf8
character_set_database  latin1
character_set_filesystem    binary
character_set_results   utf8
character_set_server    latin1
character_set_system    utf8
character_sets_dir  /usr/share/mysql/charsets/
collation_connection    utf8_general_ci
collation_database  latin1_swedish_ci
collation_server    latin1_swedish_ci
```

and I still get the same error in the same ways on my Dev vs Production environments.

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TRIGGER ...` -- see if it was created (or recreated) with latin1 instead of utf8.